# Best mini LED spotlight for Lego display case?

Tags: storage, lighting

I am currently building the Creator Sydney Opera House and planning a display case for it. I would like to light the canopies with spotlights just like the real thing, but have not found LED spotlights that are small enough to be proportional to the set. I live in Indonesia so perhaps my choices are limited. The ones I have found are big ones like for cabinets and shelves. Would appreciate your suggestions from around the world. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure exactly how many lights you are looking for, or the exact effect you are trying to create, but you may be able to get what you want using individual LEDs:

[image: White 5mm LED]

These have a diameter of 5mm, so the nose is able to fit snugly into an antistud. I've used them successfully in Technic holes and Erling bricks. The main advantage here is that you can actually brick build whatever lighting you would like to use, or just integrate this into the main model.

Here's an example of using these with Erling bricks that I [saw on Eurobricks](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=86005):

[image: Erling brick and 5mm LED]

If you aren't comfortable wiring these up yourself, you can buy them prewired with a controller from [LifeLites](http://lifelites.com/products/132).

If you would like to be a purist, you could also use a number of the PF lights (8870), as they are roughly the same as using 5mm LEDs. PF lights are 3mm LEDs encased in plastic so that they fit snugly into Technic holes.

[image: PF light]

Comment: The PF lights are LEDs. They're just cast into a more stud-shaped form rather than the dome-shape that 5mm LEDs use.

Comment: That's correct. I've updated the answer to make that more clear.